# Can I close already opened process using Apple's Endpoint Security Framework?

Tags: c, objective-c, macos, endpoint, macos-catalina

I have a list of process names retrieved from a server and I want to restrict access to them (total blocking - if the process is not executing do not allow opening, if it is executing close it)

The first part is solved by subscribing to ES_EVENT_TYPE_AUTH_EXEC and sending a deny response if the process path contains the process name I want to block.

However, I cannot figure out if there exists an event that all processes execute, so a matching process already running will be killed. This way I can subscribe to it and maybe make a system call containing a 'kill' command.

The full list of events provided by the Endpoint Security Framework API is [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/endpointsecurity/es_event_type_t?language=objc)

If the framework does not provide such capability, how would you approach this scenario?

Thanks.